# Sharepoint 2013 App Restrict File extension

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-addin, file

I am using an App on my site that is kind of a list and allow you to select a file.

[image: Sharepoint Screenshot]
Is there a way to restrict the file extension that the user can select? Can I do a receiver(event handler) to handle this?

I do not want to restrict the file extension for the whole site. Only for this portion.

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of app? If it's provider or auto hosted, then you should be able to control that with ASP.  If it's sharepoint, you need to either use client side validation, or the `accept` [attribute](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/07-accept.html) of the `input` tag (HTML5)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a web dev and Sharepoint is new to me. Is there a specific place where the asp code ends up for provider/hosted apps? The guy who made this is out of the office for a while and I need to get this fixed.

Comment: And if you could point me towards handling client side stuff in sharepoints it would also be highly appreciated. Put that in an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: Ain't gonna fix something built into sharepoint... The user will have to be responsible for what they upload I guess... Still don't get sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SharePoint Online, this is the list of supported file types that can be stored in SharePoint Online -

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-HA101907868.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102694293

This list is not customizable. Note that SharePoint Online does have virus protection built in to check files when they are uploaded.

Also check:

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/149796.

For workarounds:

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/239908.aspx